# How to detect on click event on dynamically added element in angular 6

Tags: angular

I want to attach on click event to dynamically added li tag in angular
I tried renderer also,

```
 const classArr: any = document.querySelectorAll('.highlight');
    classArr.forEach(element=>{
      this.render.listen(element, 'click', (target)=>{
        console.log('clicked', target);
      })
    });
```

but its not working on dynamic element.

Please help.

Comment: How do you render those `li` elements?

Comment: Why not use event binding `<li *ngFor="..." (click)="onClick()">` ?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I am getting those li from web service and I am setting those to ul  using viewchild and  this.ultag.nativeElement.innerHTML = data['liElements'];
 its not working because those are appended dynamically

Comment: So, you get piece of HTML from a webservice instead of JSON data? Is that correct? If you get some JSON data, you can simply do what @taras-d suggested.

Comment: That is json data only, but one of field of json is html li element

Answer (score 0):

```js
use event binding

    <ul>
  <li*ngFor="let i of slectedproduct"; let i = index>
    <span (click)="show(i)">{{slectedproduct.name}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
 
binding and calling`

`selectedevent;
show(ind){
this.selectedevent = this.selectedproduct[ind];
}
```